# Update : Add Li tags to each array items

Tags: javascript

So after all of your help I have reached to this stage where add input to the content area works, now i want to remove list item when user clicks on the red cross button on the right, how can I target class I added to a tags 'click-link' from outside the function?

Thanks

```js
(function(){

    var clickGo = document.querySelector('.button-go');
    var searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
    var list = document.querySelector('.list');
    var listArray = [];

    var clickGoFunc = function() {
            var searchValue = searchInput.value;

            // check if input field is empty
            if(searchValue === ""){
                
                alert("please put a value in the input field");
            
            }else{

                // check if list item already exists in the array named listArray
                if(listArray.indexOf(searchValue) == -1){
                    listArray.push(searchValue);

                        // Function for creating loop for added array items and enclosing each array item inside <li>
                        //Also adding a close button to each array item by adding <a> Tag
                        var runIt = function (){
                                for(var i= 0; i < listArray.length; i++ ){
                                    var liTag = document.createElement('li');
                                    var removeItem = document.createElement('span');
                                    var closeLink = document.createElement('a');
                                    closeLink.className = "close-link";
                                    closeLink.setAttribute('href', "#");
                                    closeLink.textContent = 'X';

                                    // adding <a> tag inside span
                                    removeItem.appendChild(closeLink);

                                    liTag.textContent = listArray[i].toUpperCase();
                                    list.appendChild(liTag);
                                    liTag.appendChild(removeItem);
                                    list.appendChild(liTag)
                                } 
                                // end of for loop
                        }; 
                        // end of runit

                        // clearing ul.list container before reloading array items.
                        list.innerHTML = "";

                        // calling runIt funtion which contains for loop  for all the array items
                        list.appendChild(runIt());

                }else{
                    alert("value already exisits");
                } 
                // end of if and else statement which is checking if value is already there is the array
                // pushing new values in the listArray array 
                // wrapping new array items in li tags and adding close button on each array item
            }
            // if statement checking if the input field is empty , if not it runs other function which checks following 
                    // end of if and else statement which is checking if value is already there is the array
                    // pushing new values in the listArray array 
                    // wrapping new array items in li tags and adding close button on each array item
            } 
            // end of clickGoFunc


    //calling function 
    clickGo.addEventListener('click', function(){
            clickGoFunc()
    });

}());
```

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}.container-header{background-color:#00628B}.row-header{min-height:120px;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:50px;font-family:oswald;padding-top:35px}.container-search-bar{background-color:#E6E6DC;min-height:75px}.container-search-inner .input-group{margin-top:20px}.container-content{padding-top:50px}.list li{background-color:#6C6C6C;padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;color:#fff;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px}.close-link{color:#fff;background-color:red;padding:3px;border-radius:3px}.list li span{float:right}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search NOMO</title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/css/style.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid container-wrapper">
      <div class="row row-wrapper">
         <div class="container-fluid container-header">
              <div class="row row-header">
                Search NOMO
              </div> <!-- row-header -->
         </div> <!-- container-header -->
         <div class="container-fluid container-search-bar">
             <div class="row row-search">
                <div class="container container-search-inner">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Add to List...">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default button-go" type="button">Add</button>
                          </span>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                 </div> <!-- row -->
               </div> <!-- container-search-inner -->
            </div> <!-- row-search -->
        </div> <!-- container-search-bar -->
        <div class="container container-content">
            <ul class="list">
                
            </ul>

        </div>
      </div> <!--row-wrapper -->
   </div> <!-- container-wrapper-->

   <!-- javascripts -->
   <script src="assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append `li`-elements to some `ul` element. You need the array only to check for existing values.

With this knowledge, your code can be simplified to (see comments in code and html):

```js
var clickGo = document.querySelector('.button-go');
var searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
var currentValues = []; // keep track
clickGo.onclick = function () {
  var searchValue = searchInput.value;
  if (searchValue === "") { // check empty
    alert("please put a value in the input field");
  } else if (currentValues.indexOf(searchValue) == -1) { // check existing
     currentValues.push(searchValue);
     var liTag = document.createElement('li');
     liTag.textContent = searchValue;
     // append the new li-tag
     document.querySelector('[data-vals]').appendChild(liTag);
  } else { alert("value already exisits"); }
};
```

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}.container-header{background-color:#00628B}.row-header{min-height:120px;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:50px;font-family:oswald;padding-top:35px}.container-search-bar{background-color:#E6E6DC;min-height:75px}.container-search-inner .input-group{margin-top:20px}.container-content{padding-top:50px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search NOMO</title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/css/style.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid container-wrapper">
      <div class="row row-wrapper">
         <div class="container-fluid container-header">
              <div class="row row-header">
                Search NOMO
              </div> <!-- row-header -->
         </div> <!-- container-header -->
         <div class="container-fluid container-search-bar">
             <div class="row row-search">
                <div class="container container-search-inner">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Add to List...">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default button-go" type="button">Add</button>
                          </span>
                          <ul data-vals></ul><!-- values container -->
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                 </div> <!-- row -->
               </div> <!-- container-search-inner -->
            </div> <!-- row-search -->
        </div> <!-- container-search-bar -->
        <div class="container container-content">

        </div>
      </div> <!--row-wrapper -->
   </div> <!-- container-wrapper-->

   <!-- javascripts -->
   <script src="assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the click event listener you have attached to `window`. It is not needed.
2. When trying to set the text of a HTML element, do not use `appendChild`. Rather, set its `textContent`.
3. Use `appendChild` in the click handler for `clickGo` to have `containerContent` append the new `li` element

```js
var clickGo = document.querySelector('.button-go');
var searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
var containerContent = document.querySelector('.container-content');
var listArray = [];
clickGo.onclick = function() {
  var searchValue = searchInput.value;
  if (searchValue === "") {
    alert("please put a value in the input field");

  } else {
    //checking if array already contains added list item
    //if it is not, push the item to the array
    if (listArray.indexOf(searchValue) == -1) {
      listArray.push(searchValue);

      // Adding li tags to the array list items
      var liTag = document.createElement('li');

      for (var i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
        liTag.textContent = listArray[i];

        containerContent.appendChild(liTag);
      }
      // if arry contains already contains list item then alert following message
    } else {
      alert("value already exisits");
    }
  }
};
```

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}.container-header{background-color:#00628B}.row-header{min-height:120px;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:50px;font-family:oswald;padding-top:35px}.container-search-bar{background-color:#E6E6DC;min-height:75px}.container-search-inner .input-group{margin-top:20px}.container-content{padding-top:50px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Search NOMO</title>
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/css/style.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid container-wrapper">
    <div class="row row-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid container-header">
        <div class="row row-header">
          Search NOMO
        </div>
        <!-- row-header -->
      </div>
      <!-- container-header -->
      <div class="container-fluid container-search-bar">
        <div class="row row-search">
          <div class="container container-search-inner">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Add to List...">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default button-go" type="button">Add</button>
                          </span>
                </div>
                <!-- /input-group -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            </div>
            <!-- row -->
          </div>
          <!-- container-search-inner -->
        </div>
        <!-- row-search -->
      </div>
      <!-- container-search-bar -->
      <div class="container container-content">

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--row-wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- container-wrapper-->

  <!-- javascripts -->
  <script src="assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, due to changes and to make this work, I was removing and adding stuff in and forget to add UL tag in the code which I pasted here, I am trying to learn javascript, this was a real help, if you have suggestions about good websites and books to learn java script please let me know.

I feel like I will be posting lots of stuff here to get help with

Thanks for your patience